# nullpointerexception error. trying to connect to the bitcoin server from my phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask, json-rpc

I am fairly new to android, java, and mainly jsonrpc...
I have been stuck on this error for some time and i dont know if it is how i have coded it that is causing the issue or if i am trying to connect to the wrong server...

If you could help, it would be GREATLY appreciated.

here is the error code and the important code:

```
09-08 12:36:12.141: W/System.err(30361): Network exception: failed to connect to /10.10.11.75 (port 18332): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
09-08 12:36:12.151: W/dalvikvm(30361): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417df2a0)
09-08 12:36:12.151: E/AndroidRuntime(30361): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-08 12:36:12.151: E/AndroidRuntime(30361): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.bitcoinapp.MainActivity.connect(MainActivity.java:219
at com.bitcoinapp.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:157)
at com.bitcoinapp.MainActivity$BitcoinConnect.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:143)
at com.bitcoinapp.MainActivity$BitcoinConnect.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-08 12:36:12.151: E/AndroidRuntime(30361):  ... 5 more
```

this is the android code that i am using at the moment... all of which is run once the user presses the button on the application. I am working off my SAMSUNG S3 MINI and not an emulator.

I have had to omit some of the content, so showing line numbers wont help, but i have added in the ones that i think are important...

```
class Connection implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new BitcoinConnect().execute();
    } 
}

private class BitcoinConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object[]> {

    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connect();
        return null;
    }
}

public class BasicAuthenticator implements ConnectionConfigurator {

    public void configure(HttpURLConnection connection) {

        // add custom HTTP header
        connection.addRequestProperty("myusername", "mypassword");
    }
}

private void connect() {                 //(line 157)

    //This is the code for the JSONRPC2-CLIENT iteraction
    // The JSON-RPC 2.0 server URL
    URL serverURL = null;

    try {
        serverURL = new URL("http://10.10.11.75:18332");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // handle exception...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Create new JSON-RPC 2.0 client session
    JSONRPC2Session mySession = new JSONRPC2Session(serverURL);

    mySession.setConnectionConfigurator(new BasicAuthenticator());

    //This is for the bitcoin BASE interaction. 
    //for the Bitcoin Payment Request
    String method = "getinfo";

    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();   
    String id = "Request001";

    JSONRPC2Request payment = new JSONRPC2Request(method, params, id);

    String jsonString = payment.toString();

    JSONRPC2Response response = null;

    Log.i("Failed0", "Failed0");

    try {
        response = mySession.send(payment);
        Log.i("response", String.valueOf(response));
        mTextView.setText((CharSequence) response);

    } catch (JSONRPC2SessionException e) {

        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
         // handle exception...
        Log.i("response", String.valueOf(response));

    }

    // Print response result / error

    if (response.indicatesSuccess()) {                 //(line 219)
        System.out.println(response.getResult());
    } else {
        System.out.println(response.getError().getMessage());
    }

}
```

I am using the JSONRPC2.0 libraries for the base code and the client code. I am trying to connect to the bitcoin testnet server. The IP there is one of many that i have tried...
I know that testnet is on port 18332 and the mainnet is 8332...
ive tried a localhost IP and that hasnt worked either.

I dont know if there is suppose to be other code that i must use in order for my phone to connect to the bitcoin server...

Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` - There's no server at that address. 10.0.0.0/8 addresses are local. Do you have this server on your lan?

Comment: The stacktrace clearly states that the exception happens in file MainActivity.java in line 219 (connect method). There you have to look for the bug. You know how to read a stacktrace, don't you?

Answer (score 2):

Lets apply some logical thinking.

According to the stack trace, the `NullPointerException` was thrown here:

```
   if (response.indicatesSuccess()) {
```

That means `response` was `null`.  (No other alternative!)

That means that the `send` call in

```
   response = mySession.send(payment);
```

EITHER returned assigned `null` to `response`, OR it through a `JSONRPC2SessionException` that you caught.

I suspect it was the latter, and that the message `"Network exception: failed to connect to /10.10.11.75 (port 18332): ..."` was logged in the process.  However, the evidence is not convincing.  (There aren't any "I/..." lines in the logcat output ...)

---

In summary, what you have done is catch the exception that told you that the `send` has failed, and then proceed to try to process the non-existent response!

The underlying problem is that you app cannot connect to `10.10.11.75` on port `18332`.  I assume that you realize that `10.10.11.75` is a [private IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses), and hence that you will only be able to connect to it if the server is on your local network.

Comment: +1 for the step-by-step explanation, it shows beginners how to investigate such bugs by themselves so that they don't come to SO each time a NPE is thrown.